# How do I generate set partitions of a certain size?

Tags: ruby, set, data-partitioning, powerset

I would like to generate partitions for a set in a specific way: I need to filter out all partitions which are not of size N in the process of generating these partitions. The general solution is "[Generate all “unique” subsets of a set (not a powerset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643812/generate-all-unique-subsets-of-a-set-not-a-powerset)".

For the set `S` with the following subsets:

```
[a,b,c]
[a,b]
[c]
[d,e,f]
[d,f]
[e]
```

and the following 'unique' elements:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f
```

the result of the function/method running with the argument `N = 2` should be:

```
[[a,b,c], [d,e,f]]
```

While the following partitions should be filtered out by the function/method:

```
[[a,b,c], [d,f], [e]]
[[a,b], [c], [d,e,f]]
[[a,b], [c], [d,f], [e]]
```

The underlying data structure is not important and could be arrays, sets or whatever.

---

Reason: I need to filter some partitions out before I have the full set of all partitions, because the function/method which generates all partitions is rather computationally intensive.

---

According to "[Generating the Partitions of a Set](http://compprog.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/generating-the-partitions-of-a-set/)", the number of possible partitions can be huge: 44152005855084346 for 23 elements. My data is 50-300 elements in the starting set, so I definitely need to filter out partitions that have size not equal to N before I save them anywhere.

Comment: are you using `Set` objects, or arrays?

Comment: Why does `N=2` produce sets which have three elements? Are you using zero-based counting? Or is that the number of subsets in the resulting set?

Comment: @Phrogz, N is the number of subsets in the resulting set.

Comment: If you are using arrays, you should write so in the question. In the question, you write as if they are sets, and that is making it confusing.

Comment: Are you saying that `S = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b"], ["c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["d", "f"], ["e"]]`?

Comment: the Tin Man, if you are asking if a, b, c, d, e, f can be in different subsets of S, then yes. S is a set of sets. However I do not see any difference between [[a,b]] and [["a","b"]]. There is a difference between [[a,b], [a,b,c]] and simply [a,b]. The former is a set of sets, the latter is just a set.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the `partitions` as given by Frederick Cheung that you linked, do:

```
partitions.select{|partition| partition.length == 2}
```

Comment: thanks, but I can not use this obvious solution due to the fact that I need to filter the partitions out right in the process of their generation.