# How does sofs:partitions in Erlang work?

Tags: erlang, set, data-partitioning

*Note: This question is based on rethinking of my previous similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646396/how-do-i-generate-set-partitions-of-a-certain-size).*

I would like to know if Erlang's [sofs:partition](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/sofs.html#partition-1) does the same thing which is described in Wikipedia's page about [Set partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set).

If it does, how can I get the following result?

Given a data structure (a set of sets or a list of lists):

```
   [a,b,c]
    [a,b]
    [c]
    [d,e,f]
    [d,f]
    [e]
```

which contains the following unique elements:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
```

the result of running the function with the argument `N = 2` should be:

```
[[a,b,c], [d,e,f]]
```

While the following partitions should be filtered out in the process of executing `sofs:partition`:

```
[[a,b,c], [d,f], [e]]
[[a,b], [c], [d,e,f]]
[[a,b], [c], [d,f], [e]]
```

Can I do this with sofs:partition? If yes, can I do it iteratively, throwing out the partitions of `length(Partition) =/= N` during the execution? Is it possible to somehow redefine the `sofs:partition` function to introduce the N argument?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can just pass the result of sofs:partition to lists:foldl and filter out the partitions with wrong length manually.

If it does not fit your task (for example second run is unacceptable), you can just go take a look at [sofs sources](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/sofs.erl), use it as example and make your own function that does exactly what you need in one pass.