# Get all possible subsets - preserving order

Tags: ruby, algorithm, subset

This is a follow up to this question:
[Generate all "unique" subsets of a set (not a powerset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643812/generate-all-unique-subsets-of-a-set-not-a-powerset/8644157#comment12370703_8644157)

My problem is the same, but I think there might be a more optimized solution when order of items in the new subsets and across the subsets needs to be preserved.

Example:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Would result in:

```
[[1], [2], [3]]
[[1, 2], [3]]
[[1], [2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've [already answered this question for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9185520/916657), so I quickly ported my solution over to Ruby:

```
def spannings(lst)
  return enum_for(:spannings, lst) unless block_given?

  yield [lst]
  (1...lst.size).each do |i|
    spannings(lst[i..-1]) do |rest|
      yield [lst[0,i]] + rest
    end
  end
end

p spannings([1,2,3,4]).to_a
```

See my other answer for a complete explanation of how and why this works.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand it correctly, you want to insert "delimiters" into a list, to partition it.  Taking your example, and using the `|` character to indicate the delimiter,

```
1 2 3
1 2|3
1|2 3
1|2|3
```

are the solutions you want.

In a list (I'm calling it a list and not a set because you need the order preserved) of `n` elements, there are `n-1` potential positions for a delimiter.  In the example above, there are two positions.  In each position, a delimiter might or might not be present.

You can use the binary representation of numbers from `0` to `2^(n-1) - 1` to list all possible arrangements of delimiters.  In your example, this'll be number from 0..3.

```
0:  00
1:  01
2:  10
3:  11
```

Comment: This has been really helpful. Since I need combinations with exact number of delimiters, I found my problem can also be specialized to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851134/generate-all-binary-strings-of-length-n-with-k-bits-set  but since I have small sets the function given and filtering out non fitting combinations is good for now.